# How to create a jar file in J2ME?

Tags: java-me

I want to create a `wizard`-like application when I create my `Form`s. I want then a `class` which I will use everytime I want to create a `Form`. So I want to create a `jar` because I may use it with other `J2ME` projects. So how to create a `jar` in `J2ME` ?

Answer (score 1):

To create a jar file from sun wireless toolkit open the project which you have to create a jar file of---

Project-->Package-->Create Package

click on the above mentioned buttons and your jar file is created.

It is stored in the bin folder of the application